# SOURCE error 2?

Tags: mysql, windows

When i try to source an sql file i get the error:

```
mysql> source C:/Users/tom/Documents/insert.sql

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'C:/Users/tom/Documents/insert.sql', error: 2
```

I have checked the file path, which looks fine to me. I have also tried `\. C:/Users/etc`

I am trying to source the sql file which holds insert statements for particular tables. All the statements in the file work when entered manually. What else could i be doing wrong?

Have tried using both backslash and forward slash when using this command

Comment: wouldn't windows environments expect "\" as a path divide?

Comment: Try `type "C:/Users/tom/Documents/insert.sql"` will fail, then try with backslash and it should work. So here use backslash. 2 = file not found. Despite your try with backslashes. Maybe quotes needed or doubling of backslashes

Comment: you call source on file in Documents and the erorr shows file in Desktop? Are you sure you have checked the file path?

Comment: What happens if you run in cmd: mysql < C:/Users/tom/Documents/insert.sql ?

Comment: Hmm doubling up slashes didn't work and neither did quotes. Using opposite slash doesn't seem to help either. @Petr mistype sorry, fixed

Comment: Just tested with 5.5: the `mysql` tool doesn't care about slash type and ignores case. Even `source C:/Users\\\\tom///documents/Insert.sql` works fine. Are you completely, absolutely, positively sure that the path is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a problem of access right on the file (the file is being accessed by the `mysqld` server process, not yourself). Try placing the file into the data folder of MySQL, then import it from this location. The location of data folder depends on your distribution and on your own configuration.

Alternatively, feed the SQL script directly to your `mysql` client's `stdin`:

```
mysql [all relevant options] your_database < C:\path\to\your\script.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version.
I too faced below error 2.
mysql> SOURCE home/loc/Downloads/AllTables.sql;
Failed to open file 'home/loc/Downloads/AllTables.sql', error: 2

Solution :

mysql> SOURCE /home/loc/Downloads/AllTables.sql;

Just added a '/' in front of home

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if the file exits? I have had this problem before.

This:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1p9w.png]

this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH8U3.png]

and this works:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4iqO.png]

Comment: The OP already stated "I have checked the file path, which looks fine to me.". As far as your other parts of your answer, you should include the parts here.